# Recursively search nested lists and get parent

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have a class:

```
public class Node
{
    public string name;
    public List<Node> children;

    public Node()
    {
        children = new List<Node>();
    }
}
```

I successfully search and get specific item recursively. How can I get the parent?

```
public static Node Find(Node node, string name)
{

    if (node == null)
        return null;

    if (node.name == name)
        return node;

    foreach (var child in node.children)
    {
        var found = Find(child, name);
        if (found != null)
            return found;
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: do you have any Parent Property related to the node?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to add a parent node to keep the structure simple you can change the return type and return both the node and the parent.

```
class SearchResult {
 public Node Found;
 public Node Parent;
}

public static SearchResult Find(Node node, string name)
{

    if (node == null)
        return null;

    if (node.name == name)
        return new SearchResult { Found =  node, Parent = null};

    foreach (var child in node.children)
    {
        var found = Find(child, name);
        if (found != null)
                    return new SearchResult { Found =  found, Parent = node};
    }

    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Short answer : you need to keep track of it.

for example: `List<Node> children` can be some custom collection like

```
public class Children : List<Node> {

    public Node Parent {get;set;}; 
    public Children(Node pr) {
        Parent = pr;
    }
}
```

So:

```
  .....
  public Node()
  {
    children = new Children (this);
  }
  ...
```

Or, if I correctly follow your logic:

```
    //node IS a parent of found node.
    foreach (var child in node.children)
    {
        var found = Find(child, name);
        if (found != null)
            return found;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to keep a reference to the parent in your structure.

If you don't want to do that, then you can alter the `Find` function a bit.  Something like this (beware, it's written in the browser).

```
public static Tuple<Node, Node> Find(Node node, string name)
{
   return Find(node, name, null);
}

public static Tuple<Node, Node> Find(Node node, string name, Node parent)
{
    if (node == null)
        return null;

    if (node.name == name)
        return new Tuple<Node, Node>(node, parent);

    foreach (var child in node.children)
    {
        var found = Find(child, name, node);
        if (found != null)
            return found;
    }

    return null;
}
```